# Cheap way to get from Israel to Hong Kong

Tags: air-travel, budget, israel, hong-kong

I want to fly from Tel Aviv to Hong Kong.

I searched Kayak and so on.

I wonder:

1. Do travel agents have cheaper offers which I cannot find on the Internet?
2. Is there any cheaper way to get near Hong-Kong and then transport to Hong-Kong?

any other ideas?

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: I have option of 1250 dollar, but arround ~1000 dollar would be great

Comment: Yes, sometimes travel agents have cheaper deals.  I find the best plan is to find the best price I can online, and then ask a travel agent to beat that.

Comment: Cheapest of all: Ride a bicycle. That desert will be a biotch though.

Comment: 1250$ is not little for that route assuming economy class- depending on period and exact date. try change dates and days of week as well as airlines - and you will be surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask on [Flightfox](http://flightfox.com) - they have experts who will do all that searching for you, and often have serious skills at sniffing out that cheap flight.

It costs,  but if they don't beat the price you can find it for, you get your money back, so there's not really much risk involved, and they could end up saving you quite a lot.

There's a referral link in my profile if you want 25% off.  I'm not affiliated with it, I'm just one of their 'experts' who loves hunting prices.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Momondo](http://momondo.com) for airline comparisons. I've found quite a few cheap flights through there including Israel > Hong Kong.